# How to make the font bigger?

Tags: fontsize, cv

do you know how I can make the font for my cv bigger? Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\tolerance=600  
\setlength{\textheight}{235mm}
```

just to be clear, I want to make the entire cv bigger, not a single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the first line e.g. to

```
\documentclass[fontsize=20pt]{scrartcl}
```

to use 20pt as basic font size.

Comment: @cfr Well, this is what [the manual](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) says on page 51, and it seems to work in a small experiment.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'd already deleted my comment. It just makes the class unhappy, but it does work.

Comment: @cfr But maybe the user is happy, and maybe even a reader of the cv if the option is used with care.

Comment: it actually doesn't look that nice...

Comment: Certainly not with 20pt, but maybe 13pt or 14pt still works (if you really need it bigger than 12pt). Maybe try a different font; Computer modern is probably not heavy enough for being enlarged.

Comment: Have you googled a bit for "cv latex"? There are many templates around, which actually look quite nice.